# Glyphicons CSS File that only styles the bootstrap icons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

it is my first time using bootstrap glyph icons, i have always tired to stay away from them as they have always seemed to be a pain. My question is, is there a bootstrap css file that only styles the glyphicons, as i am using :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

At the present moment, and it has changed the styling of my hyperlinks/text size/font and hoovers.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a bootstrap min css I edited some days ago. it's available on [this link](http://bluelevel.in/bootstrap-icons.min.css).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer.